# Stripe & transferring funds

Tags: ajax, laravel, payment, stripe-payments

I am currently in the process of planning & developing an integrated application using Stripe in addition to some other technologies (a combination of backbone & laravel). As a result I am using Stripejs in combination with the PHP stripe library.

I use stripejs to send Stripe their account info (for savings accounts I send country, routing and account numbers via stripes js lib, I then save off the created token in the response to the backend). I am attempting to transfer money to various recipients following charging accounts (so I have money in my stripe account) but I am a bit confused over exactly what approach to take.

My main questions are as follows.

1. If I am positive of the identities of the individual’s using the application, is verification required (5 – 10 people max will be using)?
2. If it is required what is the best approach to verifying the user using the current technique I am using (create a token, save off on the backend)?

Comment: CAn you clarify the process a bit? As I understand it 1) A user is charged using Stripe and 2) The fees from that charge are then distributed to third parties via your application using Stripe?

Comment: Exactly, without going into the details of the app, more or less a glorified transfer from one user to another.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Stripe, you don't need to 'verify identities' each time you use a token, so long as a customer has been set up for recurring use. So as long as your application is properly secured so that only the 5-10 people can use it, and can only process payments for their own accounts, you are good to go. In other words, you obviously want to do your own user verification to make sure only valid people can use the application, but you don't need to do it as far as Stripe is concerned.

That said, if you are in essence transferring money between people, you might want to go the extra distance and make sure that the user has the correct card number or bank account number each time. In which case I would use something like:

1. Get user data using tokens stored in DB.

   `$cu = Stripe_Customer::retrieve("cus_4pn93XXXXXXXXXXX");`

   `$card = $cu->cards->retrieve("card_14g7ZU4rLTyXXXXXXXXXXX");`
2. If Stripe's returned data matches user-submitted data, you know you have the correct user. In particular, if the last 4 digits of the card and the expiry date match the last 4 returned by Stripe and the Stripe returned expiry date, you can be reasonably sure (albeit not certain) that the person actually possesses the card in question.